# how to combine two different record sets In SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Have two table

**Table Model**

```
Id      int Unchecked
MakeId  int Unchecked
Name    nvarchar(255)
```

**Table Feature**

```
 FId    int Checked
```

Both table have no relation . Want a record set having both table column.

**Table Destination**

```
Id      int Unchecked
MakeId  int Unchecked
Name    nvarchar(255)   
FId int Checked
```

can not use bellow sql because i have two datasouce,one for **Model** and another one for **Feature(this one select just top 1 record)**

```
select Id,MakeId,Name,(select top 1 Fid from Feature) as Fid from Model
```

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do, since you only want a single TOP 1 result from Feature, is save that value to a variable in the Control Flow with an Execute SQL task. Then in the Data Flow, configure your source data connection, and run that to a Derived Column task. Then define a new column that uses the Feature variable you created. Then you can run the output of the Derived Column to your destination (or other task, etc).